# get google-authenticator working in other network than configured

Tags: networking, connection

Recently I enabled 2FA on my RPi 4B using google-authenticator as in this tutorial:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/setting-up-two-factor-authentication-on-your-raspberry-pi/

It worked fine, however I was configuring it being on other flat (other local network) than final destination of it's workplace. Now when I connected it in the other local network I got "Access denied" everytime when using standard OTP. I can log in without any issues using emergency scratch codes generated during configuration.

I've searched in *.google-authenticator* configuration file but it seems there are no network connections constraints.

Do I have to reconfigure 2FA whenever I change local network? Any ideas?

Comment: Time-Based OTP doesn't rely on networks, but *does* rely on date & time agreeing on both the device you are attempting to access and the device generating the code (e.g. your phone app).  The Pi doesn't have a real-time clock and relies on NTP.  Have you checked the accuracy of the clock?

Comment: @TimCampbell Well, after reboot my resolv.conf file has reseted, so i didn't have access to Internet and NTP couldnt sychronize. I fixed it  and clocks are synchronized but it didn't fix 2FA login issue. :(